# .htaccess rewrite images path

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting, load

I have site http://localhost/mobile and css try to load images from http://localhost/images, instead of http://localhost/mobile/images/.

My .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

RewriteRule ^images/(.*) mobile/images/$1
```

but it doesn't works.

Comment: Have you tried `RewriteRule ^images/(.*) /images/$1`?

Comment: doesn't work. :(

Comment: Maybe add `RewriteBase /` or use `../images/$1` in rule above?